# Lightbox/modal using Ajax, Pushstate and Popstate similar to Instagram, Pinterest, Facebook

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, pushstate, popstate

I can't figure out how to use pushstate and popstate for my ajax lightbox. What I need:

On click, open lightbox and update url. On close lightbox, update url to previous state.

On browser backward close lightbox and update url. On browser forward open lightbox again and update url.

Example: http://instagram.com/instagram

This is what I have so far:

```
function lightbox() {
    $('body').append('<div class="lightbox"/>');
}

function closeLightbox() {
    $('.lightbox').remove();
}

$(function() {

    $('.module').on('click', function(e) {

        var permalink = $(this).attr('href');

        lightbox();

        $.ajax({
            url: permalink,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                var permalinkPage = $(data).find('.permalink-content');

                // Load content etc...
            }
        });

        history.pushState(null, null, permalink);

        $('.lightbox').on('click', function() {
            closeLightbox();
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
        // Some function or if state?
    });

});
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eLpKr